# Generate list number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table look like this:

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| Grp   | Party  | Member |
+-------+--------+--------+
| FC    | Party1 | Tom    |
| FC    | Party1 | Alice  |
| FC    | Party2 | John   |
| FC    | Party3 | Mary   |
| GC    | Party2 | Anna   |
| GC    | Party4 | Alex   |
| GC    | Party5 | Diana  |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

I want to transform the table into list like this:

```
+-------+--------+
|  ID   |  Text  |
+-------+--------+
| 1     | FC     |
| 1.1   | Party1 |
| 1.1.1 | Tom    |
| 1.1.2 | Alice  |
| 1.2   | Party2 |
| 1.2.1 | John   |
| 1.3   | Party3 |
| 1.3.1 | Mary   |
| 2     | GC     |
| 2.1   | Party2 |
| 2.1.1 | Anna   |
| 2.2   | Party4 |
| 2.2.1 | Alex   |
| 2.3   | Party5 |
| 2.3.1 | Diana  |
+-------+--------+
```

I have tried `rollup` with `row_number`, but the result still far away what I want

```
;with ctx as (
    select * from @test
    group by rollup(Grp, Party, Member)
)
select row_number() over (partition by grp order by grp, party, member) as g,
        row_number() over (partition by grp, party order by grp, party, member) as p,
        row_number() over (partition by grp, party, member order by grp, party, member) as m,
        grp, party, member
from ctx
where grp is not null
order by grp, party, member
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is the SQL to generate the table, hope this can help

```
declare @test table (Grp varchar(10), Party varchar(10), Member varchar(20))

insert into @test values ('FC', 'Party1', 'Tom')
insert into @test values ('FC', 'Party1', 'Alice')
insert into @test values ('FC', 'Party2', 'John')
insert into @test values ('FC', 'Party3', 'Mary')
insert into @test values ('GC', 'Party2', 'Anna')
insert into @test values ('GC', 'Party4', 'Alex')
insert into @test values ('GC', 'Party5', 'Diana')
```

Comment: 2.1.1 should be Anna right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, thanks

Comment: FWIW the ordering in your result table doesn't quite seem right. For example shouldn't 1.1.1 be Alice and 1.1.2 be Tom?

Comment: In fact, the order is not relevant, so it can be any order sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `DENSE_RANK` to get the correct *numbering* for the `ID`. Then [`CROSS APPLY` to unpivot](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/) the data and mark which row is for the `Grp`, `Party`, or `Member`. Finally use `WHERE` to filter only those rows you need:

```
WITH CteUnpivot AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            rnGrp       = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Grp),
            rnParty     = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY Party),
            rnMember    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Grp, Party ORDER BY Member)
        FROM test
    ) t
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES
        ('Grp', Grp),
        ('Party', Party),
        ('Member', Member)
    ) x (col, [Text])
)
SELECT
    ID = CASE
            WHEN col = 'Grp' THEN CAST(rnGrp AS VARCHAR(3))
            WHEN col = 'Party' THEN CAST(rnGrp AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(rnParty AS VARCHAR(3))
            WHEN col = 'Member' THEN CAST(rnGrp AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(rnParty AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(rnMember AS VARCHAR(3))
         END,
    [Text]
FROM CteUnpivot
WHERE
    (col = 'Grp' AND rnParty = 1 AND rnMember = 1)
    OR (col = 'Party' AND rnMember = 1)
    OR (col = 'Member')
ORDER BY rnGrp, rnParty, rnMember;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/578265)</kbd>

If order does not matter for `Member`, replace `rnMember` with:

```
rnMember    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Grp, Party ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/578264)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, may I know will `cross apply` more expensive than `union all`? From the _client statistics_, seems the `union all` is slightly better

Comment: The article referenced shows that `CROSS APPLY` is the best method. However, my answer is totally different from the others as mine does not have to use `DISTINCT` 3 times. Try testing for larger number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Dense_rank()OVER (ORDER BY grp)    AS g,
                Dense_rank()OVER (partition BY grp ORDER BY party)  AS p,
                Row_number()OVER (partition BY grp, party ORDER BY member) AS m,
                grp,
                party,
                member
         FROM   @test
         WHERE  grp IS NOT NULL) 
SELECT DISTINCT grp,
                Cast(g AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [Text]
FROM   cte
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT party,
                Concat(g, '.', p)
FROM   cte
UNION ALL
SELECT member,
        Concat(g, '.', p, '.', m)
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY [Text]
```

You need to use `DENSE_RANK` for parents to generate hierarchy numbers properly. If you have duplicates in `Member` as well then change the `ROW_NUMBER` to `DENSE_RANK` inside `CTE` and add distinct to the final `select` query

**Note :** If you are using anything less than `SQL SERVER 2012` then use `+` operator for concatenation instead of `CONCAT`

Comment: Thanks @Prdp, you answer is great, but Felix Pamittan's answer sort it more properly

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I would not do this at the database level. Instead I would ensure the output is sorted by {Grp, Party, Member} and then assign "Id" values in a single pass through as you display the data.

However, if you're determined to do this in the database server for whatever reason, you could use the `dense_rank()` function to get each individual id:

```
;with cte as (
  select dense_rank() over (order by Grp) id0,
    dense_rank() over (partition by Grp order by Party) id1,
    dense_rank() over (partition by Grp, Party order by Member) id2,
    Grp, Party, Member
  from Table1
), grps as (select distinct id0, Grp from cte),
parties as (select distinct id0, id1, Party from cte),
members as (select distinct id0, id1, id2, Member from cte),
[list] as (
  select cast(id0 as varchar(50)) as id, Grp as [Text] from grps
  union all
  select cast(id0 as varchar(50)) + '.' + cast(id1 as varchar(50)), Party from parties
  union all
  select cast(id0 as varchar(50)) + '.' + cast(id1 as varchar(50)) + '.' + cast(id2 as varchar(50)), Member from members
)
select id, [Text]
from [list]
order by id
```

Comment: will `dense_rank()` expensive than loop all records to assign the `id` in programming?

Answer (score 1):

This option doesn't use `DENSE_RANK()` but `ROW_NUMBER()` but is essentially similar to other answers posted.

```
With grps As (
    Select Grp, GrpNo = Row_Number() Over (Order By Grp)
      From (Select Distinct Grp From MyTable) As MyTable),
parties As (
    Select MyTable.Grp, MyTable.Party, grps.GrpNo, PrtyNo = Row_Number() Over (Partition By MyTable.Grp Order By MyTable.Party)
      From (Select Distinct Grp, Party From MyTable) As MyTable
      Join grps On MyTable.Grp = grps.Grp),
members As (
    Select MyTable.Grp, MyTable.Party, MyTable.Member,
        parties.GrpNo, parties.PrtyNo, MbrNo = Row_Number() Over (Partition By MyTable.Grp, MyTable.Party Order By #groups.Member)
      From MyTable
      Join parties On MyTable.Grp = parties.Grp And MyTable.Party = parties.Party)
Select ID = Convert(char(5), GrpNo), 
    [Text] = Grp 
  From grps
Union All
Select ID = Convert(char(1), GrpNo) + '.' + Convert(char(1), PrtyNo),
    [Text] = Party
  From parties
Union All
Select ID = Convert(char(1), GrpNo) + '.' + Convert(char(1), PrtyNo) + '.' + Convert(char(1), MbrNo),
    [Text] = Member
  From members;
```

Comment: Don't suggest alias names like that

Comment: @Prdp how do you mean?

Comment: Instead of this `MyTable.Member,` add a alias name to your table `MyTable MT` and use it for reference `MT.Member`. It is more readable